# Display PDF in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

I've already attemped a WKWebView with no luck. Now I'm attempting to use QLPreviewController.

I've created a UIViewController and subclassed it under QLPreviewController.

In my viewDidLoad I set the delegate and data source:

```
self.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;
self.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
```

I then have the following two methods to get the number of items in the view controller and the file path:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return 1;
}

- (id<QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BOR" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pdfPath];
    return fileURL;
}
```

When I navigate to my view controller, The view is gray and displays the following text:

"No file to preview"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add a print statement/breakpoint on your `return fileURL` -> and check that the file is at that url: `FileManager.default.fileExists(_ atPath: String)`.

Comment: Yes the file does exist

Comment: Do not take the file's path and convert it to a URL. Take its URL (`URLForResource`). Before you return that, look to see if it is `nil`.

Comment: that makes sense - however it looks like none of my delegate methods are getting called. I even added the protocols in my .h like so QLPreviewController <QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate>     Is this an issue with iOS 11.0?

Comment: Are you trying preview PDF documents or do you want to see them for real? (i.e. allow navigation and the such)

Comment: You don’t mean you have subclassed QLPreviewController? That is illegal and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have subclassed QLPreviewController? That is illegal and unnecessary. You just make a preview controller, configure it, and push it or present it.